# Is Log.Info broken?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.android

I am trying to use Log.Info for Debugging.  I have found a very large limitation,  It appears that it can only display - 
`Log.Info(tag, "this is an info message");`
Notice 2 static strings

if the call looks line this -

```
Log.Info(tag, MyClass.Property.ToString());
```

or

```
Log.Info(tag, "MyValue is =" + MyClass.Property.ToString());
```

or

```
string a = "AA";
Log.Info(tag, a);
```

All of these will blow up the program and not display or track in the Logger.
Is there a better way?
How can I track var values?

Also as an after thought How can I clear the Log?

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: I am guessing that I am getting a runtime error.  The Emulator opens and I can see the program loading and then it just dumps out and displays the default emulator page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Log.Info is broken.... But here are some alternatives when debugging:

```
Debug.WriteLine();
Trace.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Since run in debugger never returns for me, I am trying to debug in run-without debug.  Therefor these ideas, even though they are good, will not work for me.

Comment: @Cadwell55: What do you mean by _"run in debugger never returns"_? You should try to solve this before trying to bypass the problem (the source of your problem can be the same). Check this link if you have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078508/debug-writeline-is-not-hit

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking for the messages?  They should show up in logcat:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

If the messages themselves are dying, you should see an exception message of why also in logcat.