# XNA 4.0 print to Visual Studio 2012 console

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xna, visual-studio-2012

When writing an XNA app -- or any app with the binary output type being `Windows Application`, [shouldn't Visual Studio send the output to the VS console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518509/redirect-console-write-methods-to-visual-studios-output-window-while-debuggi) I'm not getting this behavior, and I'd prefer to using that rather than just reading the actual Windows command prompt.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();

Comment: I saw that, as well as `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()`, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

A call to `Console.WriteLine()` absolutely should output to the Visual Studio output console.  There should be a dropdown list on the Output tab labeled "Show output from:"; is it set to "Debug"?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe it has something to do with that it's VS 2012 and the XNA app type is by default set to `Windows Application`?

Comment: No, that's not it; `Windows Application` is what I would expect, and I've debugged XNA games in 2012 before.  You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935180/visualstudio-no-debug-output) that I found.  It's possible that your Visual Studio settings got corrupted somehow.